# Does "$G$ contains no $K_n$" imply "$G$ is $n-$colorable"?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

This question occurs to me while I was thinking about the Four Color Theorem and Five Color Theorem. If we can prove that "$G$ contains no $K_n$" (where $K_n$ is the complete graph with $n$ nodes) implies "$G$ is $n-$colorable," then we can show that any planar graph is $5-$colorable, as any planar graph contains no $K_5$.

I would assume that this question is already answered somewhere, but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: For example, see the second question under "Related" to the right: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696164/why-isnt-the-four-color-theorem-be-proven-by-kuratowskis-theorem?rq=1

Comment: For $n=3$ the smallest counterexample has $11$ vertices and is called the [Grötzsch graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch_graph).

Comment: Thank you both! They are very helpful :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [clique number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) $\omega(G)$ of a graph is the largest size of a clique in it. Your question is equivalent to asking whether $\chi(G) \le \omega(G) + 1$ where $\chi(G)$ is the chromatic number. Unfortunately this is known to be false: in particular, it's known that there exist triangle-free graphs (hence $\omega(G) = 2$) with arbitrarily large chromatic number; see, for example, [here](https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Zhang.pdf).

A variant of this problem where we ask for $K_n$ minors rather than $K_n$ subgraphs is apparently an open problem, the [Hadwiger conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_conjecture_(graph_theory)).

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you so much for your answer and information!

Comment: @bof: oh, I see, my bad.