# Proving the 4-color theorem.

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

I have a question as to why the four color theorem has not been proved by hand.

I believe that to prove the four color theorem, it suffices to show that a complete graph may only be planar if it has 4 or less vertices. One may then construct a complete graph of this type, and use the Jordan curve theorem to define the interior and exterior of the graph. Finally, one can show that by introducing a new vertex to either the interior or exterior of the graph and attempting to make a complete graph with the new vertex, this new graph cannot be planar. Would an acceptable proof of this type be possible, or would it necessitate high-powered computation, as previous proofs of the four-color theorem have?

Comment: "It suffices to show that a complete graph may only be planar if it has 4 or less vertices" - this is not clear to me, please explain in detail.

Comment: Why do you believe that the four color theorem can be reduced to the bound on the size of a planar complete graph? That seems like the hard part of your argument.

Comment: So, given a planar graph with, say, 100 nodes, how do you reduce it to the four-node complete graph?

Comment: Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696164/why-isnt-the-four-color-theorem-be-proven-by-kuratowskis-theorem) essentially the same question you are asking?

Comment: Yes, that is a better-explained version of what I am asking, thank you for pointing it out.